# How to pre buffer avplayer items?

Tags: swift, buffer, avplayer, preload

I have spent the past week researching this and trying all kinds of ways but noting is working to that standard I am after.

I would like to play through a dictionary of AVPlayerItems with no buffer delay. I say Dictionary, not array because I need to attach an index to the item as I am tapping through images and videos. For this reason AVQueuePlayer doesn't seem to work for this situation.

I am creating something similar to Instagrams Stories setup. They have no delay when watching back to back videos and photos.

I realize there are a lot of questions on this subject already but a lot are quite dated now. So just wondering if I'm missing something through all the noise.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to create two AVPlayer at initial stage, and start first player and pause second player. when first player complete you can start second one

Comment: Did you solve this? Been struggling on this for a while now

Comment: ditto.  Trying to do something essentially the same.  I know all the urls in advance, and no when they need to be played (one each per page in a page view controller), but it seems not doable without waiting for each to load fresh when you get there.

Comment: Have you found any solution currently stuck on this one.